# Python w/ Ajax, cant get the variable to display on the main index view

Tags: python, ajax, flask

Here is my form and ajax code:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block app_content %}
<head>
    <title>AJAX Example</title>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->


</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <br><br><br><br>
    <form class="form-inline" action="/crowdstrike/process" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail1">Reg Key Value</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" name="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Reg Key">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br><br>
    <div id="successAlert" class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="errorAlert" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display:none;"></div>

</div>
</body>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

$('form').on('submit', function(event) {

    $.ajax({
        data : {
            name : $('#exampleInputEmail1').val(),
        },
        type : 'POST',
        url : '/crowdstrike/process'
    })
    .done(function(data) {

        if (data.error) {
            $('#errorAlert').text(data.error).show();
            $('#successAlert').hide();
        }
        else {
            $('#successAlert').text(data.name).show();
            $('#errorAlert').hide();
        }

    });

    event.preventDefault();

});

});

</script>


{% endblock %}
```

this is where i have my views for the flask app

```
@bp.route("/crowdstrike/", methods=["GET"])
@login_required_with_ip_whitelist
def index():
    log_request()
    #vm = UninstalltokenModel()
    return render_template('crowdstrike/reveal_uninstall_token.html')


@bp.route("/crowdstrike/process", methods=["POST"])
@login_required_with_ip_whitelist
def process():
    log_request()
    #vm = UninstalltokenModel()
    test = (request.form)

    #print(type(test))
    deviceID = (test['exampleInputEmail1'])

    print(deviceID)
    regkey = uninstall_token.get_token_from_aid(deviceID)
    print(regkey)
    return regkey
```

I can call the function and it brings back my variable data, but it keeps loading in a new page and not the same page, i cant figure out if its an ajax issue or flask issue!

I was using this as a guide, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZWtHsM3Y5A

```
Looks like im getting this as an error
Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> ((index):271:7)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:41964)
    at v.handle (jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js:2:39983)
```

I tried using,

as my jquery as well (not slim)

Comment: You should be using `test['name']`, not `test['exampleInputEmail1']` since you have `name : $('#exampleInputEmail1').val(),` in the AJAX call.

Comment: that breaks it...

Comment: Check your browser console for errors. It sounds like the form is submitting normally, not with AJAX.

Comment: yes, no errors, but its not on the same page...

Comment: If you put `console.log("submitting");` in the submit handler, do you see that?

Comment: I'm certain that you're doing default form submission. That's why `test['exampleInputEmail1']` works, because the form contains `name="exampleInputEmail1"`, but the AJAX calls it `name`.

Comment: where exactly does this go? console.log("submitting");  im brand new to ajax could you post a possible solution? :)

Comment: I can't post a solution if I don't know what's causing it to fail. Just put that at the beginning of the function, right before `$.ajax`.

Comment: Also make sure you have the "Preserve log" option enabled in the Console settings, so the log message isn't cleared when it refreshes.

Comment: i postede the error...

Comment: The error message indicates that you're using jQuery-Slim, not the full jQuery. The Slim version doesn't include AJAX.

Comment: ok i tried ingognito mode with a version from another thread and its still not working...

Comment: I don't think incognito mode has anything to do with it. I suspect you're loading multiple versions of jQuery in your page. Fix that.

Comment: thanks, i was able to fix that, and i triede, test['name'] but now nothing comes back, cdn issue is gone

Comment: What does `print(test)` show?

Comment: thats not the issue, but it prints a call from the function i do (eventually itll be a result of an api), its a string with numbers, "I am a blob 87B73329674A4E2BB26BD1E1A9FD4FBB
"

Comment: I never said it was the issue, this is just basic debugging. If you're not getting what you expect back, print all the objects to make sure they contain what you expect.

Comment: gotchya, just trying to understand :) but yeah that is my expected data, i was just testing the i am blob to make sure it was coming my function and returning back, can make it look just like this 87B73329674A4E2BB26BD1E1A9FD4FBB

Comment: It should be a dictionary that prints something like `{'name': 'something'}`

Comment: thanks dude! you fixed it :) feel free to reply w/ your comment and i'll mark it as complete

Comment: I still don't know what I did, except to tell you not to use jQuery-Slim.

Comment: first comment and figuring out the jquery slim :) you fixed it! and the json helped, i thought i could just use a variable

Comment: I can't post that as an answer, since there's no jquery-slim in the question code.